# Odoo10- how to sort awn map One2many

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Now I used

> menu_ids = fields.One2many('lunch.order.line','order_id','Menu')

it show all of order ID

How the way that can I show only 3 of most things in record

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to manage this, downloading this module:

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/7.0/one2many_sorted/

Then, you overrided the one2many whose order you want to alter, in your case the field was line_id.

Regards.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use '''default_order''' in the following way

```
<field name = "menu_ids">
  <tree string "Some String" default_order = "<any field> desc">
  </tree>
</field>
```

In this way your one2many field will be sorted based on  by desc order